# How to I get the first folder from a location using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to perform a move operation on a Folder from one location to the other.

And this folder contains subfolders again within itself, I need to move the very first Subfolder to the destination.

Also re-iterating that I need to move an entire folder not Files.

Comment: Define 'the first'? Alphabetical? By file node? Oldest? Newest?

Comment: Sure... the oldest one .. say there are two folders...named '202109' and '202110'  I would want to move the 202109 folder

Comment: Oldest by name then, not by modified, accessed, or created, date! So you want the script to take all of the first level directory names, parse those strings, convert them to date objects, determine the date which was longer ago than today's date, then move that directory. Can you see how your simplified question is not that at all, and more an off topic project coding task request?

Comment: If your actual requirements, are really the same as those which you've told us here, and your directories are really named like that, i.e. `yyyyMM`, those are already named in such a way as to be alphabetically ordered. So depending upon whether you get a directory list ascending aplhabetically, or descending alphabetically, you will want the first one, or the last one. What you need to do therefore is write some code which can do that, capture the one you want as a variable, then perform your move operation against that variable. _The steps are the same regardless of your scripting language._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Suppose you have these two folders:

```
ls -1l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 dawg  wheel  64 Dec 23 08:12 202109
drwxr-xr-x  2 dawg  wheel  64 Dec 23 08:12 202110
```

With pathlib you can do:

```
ur_root='/tmp/test'

from pathlib import Path 
from shutil import move

p=Path(ur_root)

for fn in p.glob('*'):
    print(fn)
```

Prints:

```
/tmp/test/202109
/tmp/test/202110
```

To only get 'the first' (which is OS dependent):

```
first=next(p.glob('*'))
```

If you want to sort the names (if you OS is delivering some other order):

```
>>> sorted(p.glob('*'), key=lambda fn: fn.name)
[PosixPath('/tmp/test/202109'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/202110')]
```

Or by modification time:

```
>>> sorted(p.glob('*'), key=lambda fn: fn.stat().st_mtime)
[PosixPath('/tmp/test/202109'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/202110')]
```

Then use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) to move it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you man totally worked for me. Saved a lot of time. Thanks once again!!

Comment: If this was helpful, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)